# How can i do something like change elements only for the selected row by EmberJs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just want to know how can i change selected row details in my table by Emberjs.

Now i have normal html table that looks like this.

[image]

So when i click Edit row it will become like this.

[image]

How can i make this happended in side Emberjs?

Thanks!

Comment: What component are you using? You can use [ember-contextual-table](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table/). This demo  is for  [your use case](https://ember-twiddle.com/2096585dc637bfd9f13ff5bc88a55d13?openFiles=templates.components.simple-table.hbs%2C).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your source code, I'm guessing you are iterating over some model to create each row of 'data'. So you can just pass the 'rowData' object into the action handler on the `Edit Row` buttons. Here's a quick example.

```html
// templates/components/my-table.hbs
<table>
  {{#each model as |rowData|}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{rowData.prop1}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.prop2}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.prop3}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.prop4}}</td>
      <td>
        <button {{action 'editRowAction' rowData}}>Edit Row</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

```js
// components/my-table.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    editRowAction(rowData) {
      // handle rowData here
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Just update the property of model, selected row will be updated automatically in the view. So if you would write `rowDate.set('prop4', 'somethingElse')` (in the editRowAction function), your view will change as well.